# Using typescript type information inside javascript files

Tags: javascript, typescript, import

if I have a file, for example `Person.ts` that looks like:

```js
class Person {
  name: string
  
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name
  }
}

module.exports = Person;
export default Person;
```

And after that, I have a javascript file that imports it and uses it like so:

```js
const Person = require("./Person")

const person = new Person("Joe")

console.log(person.name)
```

It gives me an error (in my editor) that looks like:

`Property 'name' does not exist on typeof import("<whatever>/Person").`

What I can understand is that Javascript uses the Person class from the compiled TS file, so it loses type information, but because I have enabled JS checking inside my tsconfig, it now gives an error.

Is there any way I can keep the types while importing from TS files into JS? I have tried ES6 imports too, and it results into the same problem.

Sadly renaming the file to .ts is not an option as of now.

Comment: What does your export in the TS file look like?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I forgot to include it! I'll edit my the post to reflect it.

Comment: You should only be using commonjs or ESM in your project. Don't mix the two. If you use commonjs, remove `export default`, and if you want to use ESM, you have to change your entire project to use ESM and remove `module.exports`.

Comment: What choice would be better for interop between JS and TS?
Some files use import statements, other files use require, but most use require.

Comment: In my experience ES Modules for frontend web, commonJS for node.